# Enabling High DPI makes TImage smaller at runtime than at design-time

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a Form with width 700 and height 500. I put a `TImage` on it, with `Align=alClient` and `Stretch=True` set at design-time.

At run-time, the Image pixels gets blurred. If I set the `TImage.Stretch` property to False, then at run-time the Image size is shown half of the Form size at the top-left corner. Every Image size gets smaller at run-time than its actual size.

If I disable High DPI then everything works well.

I use Delphi Tokyo. What could be the cause, and how to fix it so I can enable High DPI and all the Image size will remain the same at run-time as at design-time?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable High DPI, you are responsible for providing images in the proper size/resolution. One option you already tried is the `Stretch` property of `TImage`, but that leads to a blurry display.

The correct solution is to use a `TImageCollection` containing the same image in appropriate sizes, and a `TVirtualImage` control for the display.

Unfortunately, these two components are not available in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, so you must either upgrade to a newer version of Delphi, or take care of the image handling yourself.